# Assign value to custom property in model

Tags: laravel

How to assign value to my custom property ? I am comming from `Yii2` background and there is pretty straight forward. Here I made this:

```
protected $appends = ['sites'];
    public function getSitesAttribute()
        {
            return $this->sites;
        }
    
        public function setSitesAttribute($value)
        {
            $this->attributes['sites'] = $value;
        }
```

Trying to assign like `mymodel->sites = ['1', '2', '3']` but without success. After trying to get the `mymodel->sites` value error is thrown: `undefined property 'sites'`.

Comment: Check `public function getSitesAttribute(){ dd($this->attributes['sites']); }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `accessor` is not quite correct, note that you're not returning `$this->attributes['sites'];` but instead `$this->sites`.

```
class MyModel extends Model
{
    public function getSitesAttribute()
    {
        return $this->attributes['sites'];
    }

    public function setSitesAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['sites'] = $value;
    }
}
```

Then;

```
$my_model->sites = [1,2,3];
$my_model->sites; // [1,2,3]
```

You might want to set an initial default value for `$this->attributes['sites']` in the model constructor.

Comment: Another option would be to use `protected $attributes = ['sites' => []]` instead of the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies with the `$this->sites`. It is correct that it will throw an exception that you class instance does not have a property `$sites`.

Take a look at the [`__get`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/7.x/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L1635) method of `Model`. You can see here that a `getAttribute($key)` call is being made. Diving even deeper you would find out that at some point the following code is being executed in the [`transformModelValue`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/7.x/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasAttributes.php#L1438) method:

```php
if ($this->hasGetMutator($key)) {
    return $this->mutateAttribute($key, $value);
}
```

This piece of code calls your `getSitesAttribute` method.

[Going back a little bit](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/7.x/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasAttributes.php#L384) and you will see that it tries to retrieve the value for the `$key` (`sites`) from the attributes array by calling the `getAttributeFromArray($key)`. This will return the value stored in the `attributes` array which is where your `setSitesAttribute` mutator stores the value.

The following options I could come up with:

1. Remove the accessor to let the model retrieve the value from the `$attributes` array.

```php
protected $appends = ['sites'];

public function setSitesAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['sites'] = $value;
}
```

2. Store value in and retrieve from `$sites` property. Not sure if `$appends` still works.

```php
protected $appends = ['sites'];

private $sites = [];

public function getSitesAttribute()
{
    return $this->sites;
}

public function setSitesAttribute($value)
{
    $this->sites = $value;
}
```